# VSCode : program 'SourceFolder/test' has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger, launch

I'm trying to run from a launch.json file, so i can use gdb to debug my program in vscode.

The launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "g++ build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "SourceFolder/test",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "SourceFolder",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "g++ compile active file",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
      }
    ]
}
```

The path is correct, i can see the compiled file right there in the folder.
I can run the program via console (bash) no problem and it doesn't throw any errors, but when i run it via this method i get the following pop up:

```
Unable to start debugging. Program path 'SourceFolder/test' is missing or invalid.

GDB failed with message: SourceFolder/test: File or directory not found.

...
```

And the debug-terminal returns:

```
The program 'SourceFolder/test' has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a).
```

Could "preLaunchTask": "g++ compile active file" be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preLaunchTask name must match the `label` tag of the `tasks.json` file built by default in .vscode. Check they match.
If this isn't enough, go on your source code file, press `Ctrl+Shift+B` and see if the precompiler does everything fine. You should see something like this:

> > Executing task: g++ build active file <

> Starting build...
> /usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "sourcefilename.extension" -o "sourcefilenameNoExtension"
> Build finished successfully.

> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

If this happens to be fine then you should have the file 'SourceFolder/test' ready to run. If this went wrong you may check your `tasks.json` settings or simply change the filename to be `test.extension` and put it in the `SourceFolder` folder if you didn't yet.
If you meant the SourceFolder to be the default value for the actual opened folder then you should have write ${workspaceFolder}.
By the way you can find this and more in this guide by VSCode

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_tutorials

Here you'll find links to use G++ on your operating system.

Comment: Ok so the issue was that i didn't use ${workspaceFolder}, replacing SourceFolder with ${workspaceFolder} fixed the issue. Thanks for the help